# What is the difference between : MSIE, IEMobile, MSIEMobile?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, mobile

I am looking at User Agent (UA) strings sent by mobile web browsers and I noticed that some UAs for Internet Explorer return different information about the browser version: *MSIE 6.0; IEMobile 8.12; MSIEMobile 6.0*

For example:

**On LG GW550 :** Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows CE; **IEMobile 8.12;** MSIEMobile 6.0) LG-GW550 Obigo/WAP2.0 MIDP-2.0/CLDC-1.1 (on)

**On Asus P750 :** Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows CE; **IEMobile 7.6**) ASUSP750/1.0

**On Samsung SGH-i637 (BlackJack):** SAMSUNG-SGH-I637/UCHL1 Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; **MSIE 6.0;** Windows CE; **IEMobile 8.12; MSIEMobile 6.0**)

**Does anyone know what MSIE 6.0, IEMobile 8.12, MSIEMobile 6.0 means exactly ?**

**Also, why and when they are used ?**

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number shown for `MSIEMobile` seems to be the actual version number of the actual product.

As for the MSIE part, my strong guess is this is for compatibility. Millions of sites check for IE6 by matching the user agent header against

```
MSIE 6.0
```

which is Desktop IE6's identifier. Doing this will make those sites output their content as if it were IE6. That will have consequences in rendering (there are countless differences in how IE6 renders things as opposed to standards-compliant browsers) and other things (like lack of support for PNGs with alpha transparency).

The additional "MSIEMobile 6.0" seems to be a fusion of both pieces of information. What specific purpose or standard it serves, I do not know.